# Setting the major and minor value of iBeacon

Tags: ios, ibeacon, clbeacon, clbeaconregion

I want to set the major and minor value correctly as I enter in a region.For example,I have different queues for different kinds of customer. Like Premium and silver categories.

If a customer goes in the lane of Premium, He should broadcast his major value as the value of the lane he is standing i.e. Premium and the number as minor.

How to set these values correctly according to the current position of the customer?

```
Premium = 1;
Silver = 2;
self.myBeaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:premium minor:2 identifier:@"com.example.beacon"];
```

Comment: Do you really want the user's phone to **broadcast** a different beacon value depending on where the user is standing?  Or do you simply want to use beacons to detect which of two lines the user is in?

Comment: I guess I just want to know where user is.

Answer (score 0):

The major and minor values are set on the beacon - these are the values that are received by your app to indicate the region where the device is located.

So, in your case you would have to have two beacons, one configured the with 'premium' value and one with the 'silver' values but with the same UUID. In your app you can define the region just by UUID and examine the major/minor in `didEnterRegion` To determine which specific beacon was detected.

However, Unless the queues are a fair distance apart you may have difficulty locating the user accurately

Comment: So,You mean to tell me this is not possible ?

[Courtesy:](http://www.directionalsystems.com/products/bank_signs/open_closed)

Comment: I can't say for certain as I don't know what your geography looks like, but think about how far away you can get from your car before your phone loses connection to it's Bluetooth - typically 10m or more.  You can reduce the transmit power on iBeacons but even then I would expect the range to be several meters